# Getting Started In Information Security field

Tags: penetration-test

I want to become a pen tester/ethical hacker,what should I do in the beginning?
(I'm new to information security ,i have basic knowledge in python,will it be okay if I take CEH course,Any help is appreciated,Thank you all.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure you want to become that? It's not as cool as you think it is.

Second, you can't find lack of security controls if you don't know what are you testing. What does this mean? First you need experience. As you want to become pentester you are going to have tons of experience, minimum you need to be proficient in networking, systems administration, web applications and databases. Be proficient is not "hey, I know how to subnet, install a LAMP stack, setup a WordPress site and query a DB". You really need to know how everything is working, otherwise, you will be just another monkey running Nessus, w3af, ZAP and Metasploit.

Finally, CEH? First go to the basics. Security+.

Answer (score 0):

security+ from CompTIA is awesome. I'm halfway through the fourth edition and it's an eye opener. What the dude above me is trying to tell you, is Go fix an time piece with all the springs and gears with a shoe makers experience. Computer protocol studies are boring, drawn out, and hard to comprehend without intense or long term studies. What I suggest you do is to learn how to build a computer, identify its components. Figure out how to install an operating system from every conceivable method possible, figure out how networks work, how they talk to each other. Never ever forget the fact that if is plugged into a wall and provides an output(provides a service ie, games, networking, reheating left overs) based on input(keyboards, buttons, messages over wires or antennas) it's a computer. This is a broad world you're looking at. Specialize in a device or family of devices and study that. Since you're looking at being a 'hacker' study networking, networking, networking and networking.